# Javascript: Date string in different locale to Timestamp

Tags: javascript, date, locale

I have a time string that I need to convert into a timestamp, but it's in the timezone of another location. The location uses DST, so it isn't as simple as adding some constant offset.
For example, I want to go from
`Mar 10, 2024, 06:00:00` (America/Vancouver time)
to
`1710075600000`.

`Date.parse` works fine if the user is actually *in* America/Vancouver, but produces different timestamps if they're in Portugal.

I tried adding the target timezone to the date string, but I wasn't accounting for DST.
`Date.parse('Mar 10, 2024, 06:00:00 PST')` produces `1710079200000`. I should use `PDT` in this case, but I'm not sure how to check if a future date is in DST in a different timezone.

Comment: There's nothing built-in that parses locale-dependent date strings. You may be able to find third-party libraries that do it.